# Azure Synapse Environment setup considerations

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

If one has multiple environments(dev/qa/prod) in different subscriptions, there might be some restrictions with Azure DevOPs pipelines. I think currently Azure DevOps cannot span multiple subscription.

Considering this, will it be a good design to say have multiple synapse workspaces(one for each environment - dev/qa/prod) for each project in the same subscription but different resource groups?

Comment: Yes!  Using multiple subscriptions for this kind of requirement is much less recommended these days.  The same subscription make for a much easier life.  Given RBAC, Tags, etc., using another subscription is just a pain.  That's my experience anyway.

Comment: Thanks @Skin for sharing your thoughts

Comment: Synapse Azure DevOps CICD can support multiple subscriptions, so better to keep them in different subscription if possible. That way you can manage cost more efficiently.

Comment: @Learn2Code Can we use Azure DevOps Git Repo be uses across subscriptions?

Comment: yes, you have to just connect dev workspace with Git, for qa, uat, prod etc you will use release variable groups to parameterize subscription, resource group, name etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is always more than one way to do things but I do not think one subscription is always the right answer.  It brings a bit of risk that someone could accidentally 'deploy to prod', and although this could happen in any situation, having only one subscription makes this more likely.  The environments should of course be properly ring-fenced with permissions, resource groups, resource locks, clearly defined release pipelines with gateways etc which will help reduce that risk.

Multiple subscriptions, or at least a dedicated prod subscription housing a single prod environment and a non-prod subscription housing dev, test, QA (and other environments) is another option.  This should reduce the risk of a single subscription but introduces additional complexity.

One way to think about it then, and what is best for your organisation is to think about a grid or matrix, with axes for Risk, DevOps maturity and Complexity versus number of Azure subscriptions you have.  Ask a series of questions to help decide your position on this chart. A simple example and some sample questions:

[image: DevOps maturity chart]

Regarding "easy life", DevOps engineers and architects do not think like this and you shouldn't either.

Comment: Hey @UtkarshPal-MT, what are your thoughts on my post?

Comment: Hi @wBob , Thanks for sharing your thoughts. While this approach is quite a classical approach that has worked and I personally like it as well. At the same time I am trying to think of any limitations one might face while implementing CI-CD across subscriptions using Azure DevOps. One thing that came to me is that Azure Git Repos does not span across subscriptions.Say if we have to use multiple subscriptions having ADF, Databricks, Synapse etc for dev,uat,prod, then how the code for these will be promoted from one environment to other?

Comment: Consider an up-vote if you don't believe this to be an answer to your question.  Speak to your DevOps engineer about promotion between environments.

Comment: Consider at least having one Dev/Test subscription for non-Prod environments for the purpose of cost savings as well.  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/dev-test/#overview

Answer (score 0):

You should have a single Subscription and within that subscription you can have multiple resource groups like Dev/Prod/QA. Deploy and manage your resources for different environment under a corresponding resource group for easy and hustle free experience.

Check the below diagram for your reference.

[image]

For better understanding, refer [Microsoft official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/overview#resource-groups).

Comment: Hi @UtkarshPal-MT , this is what I am personally leaning towards. Thanks for sharing your thoughts.